# IBM Worklight 6.1: Black screen and takes time to load

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created sample application with 2 page using IBM Worklight 6.1.

When I deployed it into either Android Emulator or device, I can see a black screen and it takes time to load.

The same code I have implemented in IBM Worklight 6.0 it works better.
What could be the problem?

Continuous screenshots with time will help you to understand the problem:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Provide sample project.

Comment: page 1 list item & page 2 description.

Comment: Seriously, give us something to work with here, you are not provide code nor sample. What do you want us to tell you? W/out something to work with this is moot.

Comment: I have faced same issue too whenever i try to deploy the application  in the android device.

Comment: Idan, this problem is not specific to an application, whatever the app I install via IBM Worklight 6.1 I am getting this issue. You can try it with a simple HelloWorld application.

Comment: @IdanAdar whenever i try to install the application for the first time after Splash Screen it took several minutes to load my page and during that time i have only blank screen. This happens in worklight 6.1 only.

Comment: I do not see it happening here. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried with devices also or only the emulator? The emulator can be very slow and is out of Worklight's control.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have verified in several devices. It works the same way as similar to screenshots.

Comment: @IdanAdar Is that a problem with worklight 6.1 version? Still i am facing the problem

Comment: I have tested this myself here and applications load fast... I do not know at this time what is causing the slowdown in your case.

Comment: @IdanAdar After this now i used my same project in Worklight 6.0.The loading problem was not faced and it worked fine. It comes only in Worklight 6.1.

Comment: Does this happen only in the first launch of the application, or any launch of the application? You may also wait for 6.1.0.1 coming in early march that should address startup speed issues.

Comment: @IdanAdar, this happens at first launch. Lets hope this issue will get fixed at march release as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The recently released Worklight 5.0.6.2 and Worklight 6.0.0.2 include the following: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27040464

The upcoming Worklight 6.1.0.1 will include this enhancement as well.
This enhancement should allow for a substantial decrease in the initial loading time of an application.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue......I didn't get any fix pack for Worklight 6.1.0.1. On IBM site i can see following option when i select option to download fix pack:   

IBM Worklight Consumer Edition version 6.1.0.1 update pack

The following files implement this fix.

    6.1.0-MTWW-StudioP2-FP0001.zip (253.69 MB)
    6.1.0-WL-Pattern-FP0001.zip (94.61 MB)
    6.1.0-WL-Server-FP0001.zip (577.56 MB)
    6.1.0-WL-StudioP2-FP0001.zip (258.52 MB)
    6.1.0.1-WL.txt (5.89 KB)

Comment: Worklight 6.1.0.1 IS the fixpack.

Comment: All the four option having 6.1.0 Prefix..Which one i need to download and i have tried with 6.1.0-WL-StudioP2-FP0001.zip (258.52 MB) .Its not working

Comment: I don't know what you're using and what is your actual problem. Don't hijack questions. If you have a question then open a new question and describe YOUR specific problem. Thanks.